# Capitalizing Words from a Text File

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating a program that would convert all the letters in the words (173528 from a text file) from lower case to upper case letters.

Here's the function:

```
void CapitalizeDictionary(char *Words[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while (Words[i] != '\0') {
        Words[i] = Words[i] - 32;
    }
    i++;
}
```

There are initialization, printing and freeing functions. Here's my main function:

```
int main() {
    char *Words[NWORDS]; 

    Initialize(Words);

    Cap(Words);  //lowercase to uppercase

    Print(Words);     
    Free(Words);      

    return 0;   
}
```

I've tried to change it multiple number of times but it won't work.

Comment: `while (Words[i] != '\0') { Words[i] = Words[i] - 32;` : type of `Words[i]` is `char*`.

Comment: Use [toupper](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_toupper.htm)

Comment: You're incrementing `i` _outside_ the loop.

Comment: "It won't work" is a very bad description of your problem. Can you please elaborate? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to post the rest of the program and the error messages, or what you are getting for output,  and what you expect

Answer (score 7):

1. `Words[i]` is a `char*`, not a `char`, but you're comparing it to `'\0'`.
2. `i` doesn't change inside the loop.
3. You're only iterating the top-level array, not the strings in that array.

Assuming that the `Words` array and the strings in it are null-terminated, the following should work:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void CapitalizeDictionary(char *Words[])
{
   for (int i = 0; Words[i] != NULL; i++)
      for (int j = 0; Words[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
         Words[i][j] = toupper((unsigned char)Words[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: ive placed i inside the loop. Is there a way to change it without the use of toupper?

Comment: Yes if all letters are lowercase you can use `Words[i][j] -= 32;`. I can't think of any reason to avoid `toupper` though.

Comment: `toupper` is better - it will also work with numbers, uppercase letters etc. It is safer.

Comment: `toupper(Words[i][j])` -> `toupper((unsigned char)Words[i][j])`.  Passing a `char` value to `toupper` may cause undefined behavior if `char` is signed and the value is negative.  You should also use `size_t` for the type of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @tuple_cat - Added `(unsigned char)`  for you

Answer (score 0):

A fast way, if the optimizer didn't already do this for you, is:

```
     for (char *p = Words[i]; *p; p++)
         if (*p>='a' && *p<='z')
             *p -= 32;
```